# jspm bundle code in subdirectory that is served as root

Tags: jspm

I am trying to create a [self-executing bundle](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md#creating-a-self-executing-bundle) of an application, but jspm can't find what it's looking for.

I have the following folder structure

[image]

The `src` directory contains all of the JavaScript, but it is hosted by node as if it were the root. `jspm_packages` is hosted as if it were inside the root, making normal module `import` without a path possible (ie `import React from 'react'`)

[image]

The app runs just fine, but when I try to build it fails because it doesn't know to look in the `src` directory *and* the `jspm_packages` directory for modules. Is there a way to fix this without changing the folder structure or the root-hosting?

I am ok with moving the `system.config.js` file into `src` if that makes this possible)

## EDIT

This is easy if you move `jspm_packages` into `src`.

in `package.json`

```
"jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "baseURL": "src"
    },
    "configFile": "src/system.config.js"
 }
```

This will put both `system.config.js` and `jspm_packages` in `src` (don't use a `baseUrl` in `system.config.js`), and bundling will work. The major drawback here is the `src` folder no longer contains only the project code; it now also contains library code. Performing folder searches becomes harder, and I just prefer the idea of a folder with all of *my* code in it.

## EDIT2

After thinking about this problem more, I guess what I am really after is a method to specify an alternate `path` configuration during bundling. Based on my reading of the docs, this appears to be unsupported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your **baseUrl** to be the root (i.e. "/") and then set the **path** for your source code on the paths property like this:

```
System.config({
    baseURL: "/",
    paths: {
        "*": "dist/*",
        "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
        "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
    }
})
```

Full working example can be seen [here](https://github.com/ricardobrandao/NetPonto-ES2015/blob/master/app/config.js).

Furthermore, if you need to change you paths **just for bundling** you could use the jspm-cli in a gulp task and override your builder configuration like this:

```
var jspm = require('jspm');

gulp.task('task', function () {
    var builder = new jspm.Builder();
    builder.loadConfigSync('pathToYourConfigFile');
    builder.config({
        paths: {
            '*': 'pathToYourCode'
        }
    });

    builder.bundle('yourOptionsHere');
}
```

Comment: That does not work for development, since it tries to look in the `src` directory for files that are served as root. It *does* work for bundling though. I am looking for a solution that does both.

Comment: If you take a closer look to that repository you will see that I have two different .config files - one for development that serves from "/dev" and another one for production that serves from "/dist". If you want to use the same config file you will have to override the systemjs config in runtime I guess. P.S. I don't really understand the down vote on this answer

Comment: I downvoted it because it doesn't answer the question. Additionally, the critical detail *isn't even in the answer*, its in a link. StackOverflow encourages answers to [contain all relevant parts in the answer itself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). That being said, if you include the bit about switching config files, and explain in your answer how I could switch config files just for bundling, that would solve the problem.

Comment: After looking through the jspm docs, I am not convinced the cli offers a way to specify the config file. Even if it did, that would mean maintaining a seperate one after each `jspm install`. This is a suboptimal solution.

Comment: I was on my iPad and that's why I did not produce a better answer, sorry. I have edited my answer with your inputs. If you only want to change the paths for bundling, then you can override the jspm config file on a gulp task and then use the jspm API to bundle your files.

Comment: This is a significant improvement. I didn't realize you could alter the paths with the node API.